# Jumbo ad for teams

Tags: support, bug, advertising

This ad is "yuge". It breaks the flow of the sidebar!

[image]

Comment: Hm, "why not at work?"... do they think most SO users visit SO from their boat?

Comment: I have visited SO from a boat.

Comment: I wish I had more opportunities to be on a boat, but I live in the middle of a desert.

Comment: Some myth in mind as always, those who have higher reputation, the ads are reduced for them. it's just a vice versa after seeing huge ads.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being down-voted...

Comment: @Script47 I even did a freehand circle

Comment: @DanielA.White ah, now I see why... That circle looks like a deformed loaf of bread. -1 it is.

Comment: It's too smooth of a "freehand" circle. _Real_ Freehand Red Circles™ look more like this excellent example from Abbas: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB8RQ.png

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat you can blame Apple Preview

Comment: "You already use us", no I don't.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך Depends on your personal definition of "use".

Comment: So... what is that cube? Am I the only one seeing [the Kaaba in Mecca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaaba)?

Comment: I'm tempted to post "Yes, it is" as an answer. Shall I or shall I not, that's the huge question here.

Comment: @WelcometoStackOverflow the last time I was on a boat, I indeed visited Stack overflow via my phone.

Comment: @WelcometoStackOverflow Stack Overflow Boat Owner's Union, Unite!

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms welcome to Boat Overflow

Comment: if you take the sum of all square windows, devide the number by the trees and multiply that number with the sum of buildings an then substract the amount of rectangular windows multiplied with the amount of different hex-colors used in this ad you get..

Comment: @DonQuiKong I did it for you, so that you wouldn't have to endure the -10 votes

Comment: @DavyM Living in a desert does not preclude you visiting SO [from a boat](https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/1400/e75cd42665859.598bd51d9e7f1.jpg).

Comment: @Magisch the last time I was on my phone, I indeed visited a boat via Stack overflow.

Comment: @Draco18s You know what? You're right. I'm gonna hop on [this bad boy](https://amp.businessinsider.com/images/5605aa579dd7cc0f008bd2d9-480-360.jpg) and check Stack Overflow.